# What is the _sopen_s() equivalent for the open() function?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Microsoft has deprecated _open in favor of _sopen_s.
What are the recommended equivalent arguments?

Comment: Here is the answer (I'm not allowed to answer my own question).
For

    `int fd = _open(name,oflags);`

Replace with

    `int fd;
    errno_t errno = _sopen_s(&fd,name,oflags,_SH_DENYRW,0);`

Comment: Of course you're allowed to answer your own question... just not immediately after you had posted your question.  Try putting that in as an answer again.

Comment: Ah, inflation of the arguments. Win32-itis.

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer a question within 8 hours of asking it. I'm in the 8 hour jail. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well now I can post my nicely formatted answer, so here it is:

For

```
int fd = _open(name,oflags);
```

Replace with

```
int fd;
errno_t errno = _sopen_s(&fd,name,oflags,_SH_DENYNO,0);
```

The reason I posted this Q&A is that it provides an important bit of non-obvious info that Microsoft didn't provide. I agree that the _sopen_s is a poor replacement for _open. I only researched this topic because I was fixing a bug caused by the wrong arguments being supplied to _sopen_s. The _sopen_s was only in the code to get rid of the compiler warnings; the original _open call was fine.

Comment: So you as well tried to pass 0 as the fourth argument? They could at least make it so that passing zero means that you don't care about that flag or option. Currently passing 0 as this argument raises an exception and terminates your application.

Comment: If I spy MS code of _wopen I see the following: errno_t const _Result = _wsopen_dispatch(_FileName, _OFlag, _SH_DENYNO, _PMode, &_FileHandle, 0); so it's using SH_DENYNO instead of _SH_DENYRW.

Comment: You are correct, it is _SH_DENYNO. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best recommendation is ignoring all of Microsoft's **politically motivated** deprecations. Their "safe" functions offer no actual safety advantages over correct use of the existing, standard C or POSIX-like functions, and if used incorrectly, they are just as "unsafe" as the functions they aim to replace.

Comment: That's a very provocative statement.  Do you have some evidence to back it up?

Comment: It's been discussed on SO before, but it doesn't really require evidence, just some basic reasoning ability...

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to the phrase "politically motivated". That does call for evidence, as opposed to the rest of my answer which is just that there's nothing "safer" about the "safe" functions. Of course if you make a gratuitiously incompatible interface to do something that existing interfaces do perfectly well, and falsely describe the existing standard interfaces as "unsafe" and even add annoying compiler warnings to try to prevent people from using the standard interfaces, it's pretty clear you have a motive to undermine standards.

Comment: @R: just use standard functions correctly, and then define `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `_STL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I suggest to use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  unless there is a good reason not to do so. On Linux "open" maps to kernel function, on Windows - to library function, that uses "CreateFile" anyway.
As per portability, this function is somewhat more portable on Microsoft platforms (Win32/64/CE). And, naturally, not available on *nix.

Comment: I think the OP wasn't looking for a solution that would require that he also change all the reads/write/whatever calls too.